# Inner product between a state and its derivative (quantum mechanics)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, differentiation, quantum-states

I seem to have $\langle\varphi|\frac{d}{dt} \varphi\rangle=0$ for any ket $|\varphi\rangle$, which I doubt very much...

For any quantum state $|\varphi\rangle$, we know it's normalized and therefore $\langle\varphi|\varphi\rangle = 1$.

Now $$\frac{d}{dt} \langle\varphi|\varphi\rangle = 2\langle\varphi|\left(\frac{d}{dt} \varphi\rangle\right)$$

So $\langle\varphi|\left(\frac{d}{dt} \varphi\rangle\right) = \langle\varphi| \frac{d}{dt} \varphi\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} 1 = 0$?

Is it actually true? If not, what mistake(s) am I making?

---

**EDIT**: I appreciate much the reference to Schrödinger Equation in the answers, which relates this question to physical intuitions. However, IMHO it needs to be noted: the state $|\varphi;t\rangle$ in the question doesn't have to be actually involved in any dynamics, i.e. it's time-dependence doesn't have to be related to a Hamiltonian. For example, $|\varphi;t\rangle$ can be defined as the ground state of a time-dependent Hamiltonian. Therefore, the Schrödinger Equation approach is not a necessary.

Comment: Regarding your edit, keep in mind that when you say $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$, you have **assumed** certain dynamics: you're claiming that the state changes in a specific way so that the inner product is conserved, in other words, you are claiming unitary evolution in time. Now, the Schrodinger Equation provides such a time-evolution, but it is perhaps not the only way, you could come up with something else, but the argument below would generalise quite simply. Nevertheless, a state's dependence on time *is* intricately linked to the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Philip Thanks for the comment! I wanted to say that this question can be simply mathematical. The derivative rule of inner product in a complex space would already suffice, and the introduction of Hamiltonian and using the knowledge that Hamiltonian is an Hermitian operator (because it's an observable) is a great supplement, but not necessary to the derivation.

Comment: @Philip Could you elaborate more on "a state's dependence on time is intricately linked to the Hamiltonian" using the example in my edit: $|\varphi;t\rangle$ defined as the ground state of a time-dependent Hamiltonian?

Comment: I understood the edit, my point is that for a general vector, there is no reason for $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$, it could be, for example, $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = f(t)$. If you assume it to be $1$, then what you mean is that $| \psi(t) \rangle = \hat{U} |\psi(0)\rangle$, where $U$ is a unitary operator, since only then is the inner product conserved. My point being that your question is quite *as* general as you may think, it assumes a certain type of time-evolution.

Comment: @Philip I have a slightly different opinion about this: it doesn't require a unitary operator to preserve norm. For example, any operator whose eigenspace corresponding to a unitary eigenvalue contains $|\psi\rangle$ would preserve the norm.

Comment: In the case of QM, a formal solution to the Schrodinger Equation shows that $|\psi(t)\rangle = \exp(-i \hat{H}/\hbar t) |\psi(0)\rangle$, so that the unitary operator is $\hat{U} = \exp(-i\hat{H}/\hbar)$. Indeed, this is called the "time evolution operator"! The hamiltonian thus generates the time evolution of a quantum state. Now, if  you wished to have a more "wacky" time evolution, it would still need to be unitary if you want the norm conserved, meaning that $\hat{H}$ will have to be replaced by some *other* Hermitian operator, but the argument in my answer would be nearly identical!

Comment: I suppose. Perhaps this is just semantics, but if you're going to talk about time evolution, I would assume (i) that it is not dependent on the choice of the state $|\psi\rangle$ and (ii) that some notion of dynamics has been defined. But that's beside the point, I think you've got the core of my argument otherwise :)

Comment: "I seem to have ⟨φ|ddtφ⟩" Did you mean to follow this with "=0"?

Comment: @Acccumulation Thank you! Fixed (after 4 months)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner product in Quantum Mechanics is not symmetric if you interchange the terms, since $$\langle \phi | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | \phi \rangle^*.$$

As a result, $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = \Big\langle \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}t}\Big|\psi\Big\rangle + \Big\langle \psi \Big| \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}t}\Big\rangle = 2 \,\text{Re}\left(\Big\langle \psi \Big| \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}t}\Big\rangle\right).$$

Thus, the only thing you can say using this argument is that $\Big\langle \psi \Big| \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}t}\Big\rangle$ is purely imaginary.Of course, you could arrive at this same conclusion from the Schrodinger Equation: $$i\hbar \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}|\psi\rangle = \hat{H}|\psi\rangle \quad \quad \iff \quad\quad \Big\langle \psi \Big|\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\psi\Big\rangle = - \frac{i}{\hbar} \langle \psi | \hat{H} | \psi\rangle.$$ Since $\langle \psi | \hat{H} | \psi\rangle$ is the expectation value of the Hamiltonian, it must always be real, and so the right hand side is purely imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

You did a mistake in evaluating the derivative.

$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle \psi \vert \psi \rangle = \left( \frac{d}{dt} \langle \psi \right)\vert\psi \rangle +  \langle \psi \vert \left( \frac{d}{dt} \psi \rangle \right)  \neq 2  \langle \psi \vert \left( \frac{d}{dt} \psi \rangle \right). $$

Recalling the Scrodinger equation $\vert \dot \psi \rangle= (- i \hat H) \vert \psi \rangle$, and $\langle \dot \psi \vert = \langle \psi \vert (i \hat H)$, you see how the sum of the two terms is equal to zero:

$$ \left( \frac{d}{dt} \langle \psi \right)\vert\psi \rangle +  \langle \psi \vert \left( \frac{d}{dt} \psi \rangle \right) = i \langle \psi \vert \hat H \vert \psi \rangle - i \langle \psi \vert \hat H \vert \psi \rangle = 0. $$

To be more accurate,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle \psi \vert \psi \rangle = 2   Re \biggl[\langle \psi \vert \left( \frac{d}{dt} \psi \rangle \right)\biggr],$$
which happens to be zero and makes or theory consistent $:)$ . This may have many consequences, but I' m not aware of any resulti towards this direction.