# A derivation of an equation involving singular Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, adiabatic

I was trying to follow the derivation of an adiabatic theorem in the Appendix F.1 of [Jordan, S. P. (2008). Quantum computation beyond the circuit model](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2307).

The author claims that, for the sake of this derivation, it's safe to assume the ground state of a time-dependent Hamiltonian always has energy $E_0(t) = 0$. Also, reparameterization of time is $s = \frac{t}{T} \in [0,1]$. Then the author goes from

$$H(s)|\phi_0(s)\rangle = 0\label{eq:1}\tag{1}$$

to

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle = -G\frac{\mathrm{d}H}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle ,\quad \text{where $\displaystyle G=\sum_{j\neq 0}\frac{|\phi_j\rangle\langle\phi_j|}{E_j}$} \label{eq:2} \tag{2}$$

and **I'm having trouble following this step from (\ref{eq:1}) to (\ref{eq:2})**.

---

Here is what I currently have: taking derivative of (\ref{eq:1}), we get

$$H\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}H\right)|\phi_0\rangle = 0 \label{eq:3}\tag{3}$$

Expanding $H$, considering $E_0 = 0$, we have $H = \sum_{j}E_j|\phi_j\rangle\langle\phi_j| = \sum_{j\neq0}E_j|\phi_j\rangle\langle\phi_j|$.

Now if we multiply (\ref{eq:3}) by $G$, we have

$$\big(I - |\phi_0\rangle\langle\phi_0|\big)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle + G\frac{\mathrm{d}H}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle = 0$$

which differs from (\ref{eq:2}) by the $\big(I - |\phi_0\rangle\langle\phi_0|\big)$ factor that I can't explain, since $\langle\phi_0|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle$ is in general non-zero ([Inner product between a state and its derivative (quantum mechanics)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/585530/276458)).

What am I missing or mistaking here?

Comment: well i think $\langle\phi_0|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle$ is just zero. at least this is what he assumes.

Comment: @physshyp Do you mind explaining more? I believe in general $\langle\phi_0|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\phi_0\rangle$ is not zero (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/585530/276458)?

Comment: @physshyp Hello! Just wanted to ask again because I'm still curious :p

Comment: see section  10.1.2 of grifits intro to qm 2nd ed

Comment: also you are rigth this is just what he assumes read that ref btw